# No IMEI on Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: imei

A week ago, my sister gave me her Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830I. She said that she could not call or text anyone and could not receive anything. I looked around on her phone and on the Internet to find the root of the problem. I found that the phone had no IMEI number. I typed `*#06#` in the keypad of the phone and a box appeared. It had the words "IMEI" but there was no number under it. When I go to `Settings > About phone > Status`, this is what it says:

```
Network: T-mobile UK
Signal strength: -83 dBm 14 asu
Mobile Network type: UMTS
Service state: Out of service
Roaming: Not roaming
IMEI: Unknown 
IMEI SV: 01
```

I hardly know anything about Android, so could you please explain everything simply?

Comment: Most phones will have the IMEI number written on the back of the phone, remove the cover and the battery to see the number.

Comment: That is a bit tangential to the issue. While it's correct that most phones have IMEI number written somewhere, the issue here is the phone itself doesn't recognize it as it's lost/removed/deleted (it's possible, there are many cases similar like this)

Comment: Is the phone rooted or has a custom ROM been installed?  A factory reset + flashing the stock ROM might correct this.